Comparing stability of acetate and formate with respect to inductive effect
According to my teacher, the order for +I effect is
$$\ce{-CH2-} > \ce{-NH^-} > \ce{-O^-} > \ce{-COO^-} > \ce{-R} > \ce{-H}.$$
So, $\ce{-COO^-}$ must have more pronounced +I effect compared to $\ce{-CH3}$ and the electron density must shift towards $\ce{-CH3}$ in $\ce{CH3COO-},$ which reduces the charge on oxygen stabilizing the molecule. On the other hand, $\ce{HCOO-}$ will not show inductive effect.
But while explaining this problem my teacher shifted the electron density towards $\ce{-COO^-}$ because this increases the charge towards the right in $\ce{CH3COO-}$ making it less stable than $\ce{HCOO-}.$
Where I am going wrong?

CH3 shifts electron density to COO(-), but note that electron is negatively charged and therefore CH3- pushes electron into an already negative COO(-). This increases the charge on COO(-), and is relatively unstable when compared to HCOO(-), because H does not push electrons.

That is what I was asking, why is CH3 shifting electron and not COO(-) because of the order. @Thickduck
